# jquery remove event listener from the e.target

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry I am bit lost in jquery after awhile not using.

Just wondering why when I use e.target.off it throw error, how do I implement with e.target to remove event listener.

```
$('#ownerdobday, #ownerdobmonth, #ownerdobyear').on('blur', function(e){
    //Works
    $(this).off('blur');

    //Not work
    e.target.off('blur');
});
```

Any help or suggestion is much appreicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.target` is not a jQuery object, but `off` belongs to jQuery.

Try this:

`$(e.target).off('blur')`

This can be thought of as "grab the jQuery object for the e.target DOM element".

Answer (score 1):

`e.target` refers to the DOM node element, wrap it in jquery object to use jquery's method `.off()`: `$(e.target).off('blur');`

Answer (score 1):

[`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) is a DOM object. jQuery functions such as `.off()` can only be used on jQuery objects.

In your case, `$(this)` and `$(e.target)` are equivalent.